# Azure - Assign multiple cards for different services?

Tags: azure

I am running a number of different services (Pay As You Go subscriptions) on Azure including: Blob storage, Databases and web apps.

I have a debit card associated with the account that is charged monthly for my usage.

My question is **can I use multiple cards for different services**? For example can I assign the cost of one of the databases (I currently have 3 on the Azure account) to a specific card and charge all the other services to another card?

Answer (score 0):

you can't. Using default portal modules this isn't possible.
Any way you can try calling to azure support help desk, may be they can help you or at least tell you the final word about that.

Just follow this link to open a ticket. https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade